# How to check LDAP connections / how it checks for valid usernames/passwords?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We currently have wso2 connection to a server using ldaps, our question is how can we check what url is being actually hit? and how do we know if a user changes their password that the system is actually pinging the server and not using cache credentials?

Comment: As per the given details, I'm not clear on your usage of LDAP with WSO2 IS. Do you have an LDAP server as a WSO2 IS primary userstore / secondary userstore? ` user changes their password` here do you mention the changing LDAP system user credentials or stored users' credentials in the userstore?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna it is primary user store, we recently updated the url but we cant see anywhere in the logs if it is hitting the new url.

Comment: Could you please mention the IS version that you use? After changing the URL don't use see the list of users and do you get any issues when updating users?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [correlation logs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/deploy/monitor/work-with-product-observability/) to observe the communication between IS and LDAP.